# Кол-во цифр после запятой больше 20 в Math.random()

Tags: javascript

`Math.random().toFixed(20)` позволяет генерировать случайное число от 0 до 1 с 20-ю цифрами после запятой.
А каким образом я могу генерировать случайные числа с большим кол-вом цифр?
Ведь у `toFixed` лимит в максимум 20 цифр.
К примеру, мне нужен генератор рандомных чисел с 30 цифр после запятой.

Comment: Уточните, а зачем вам генератор рандомных чисел с 30 цифрами после запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип float хранит 20 знаков после запятой.
Если надо 30 знаков, то в виде строки можно так получить:

```
Math.random().toFixed(20) + Math.random().toFixed(10).substring(2)
// "0.121046188135246923782935929242"
```

Но при преобразовании к float все равно останется 20 знаков:

```
parseFloat(Math.random().toFixed(20) + Math.random().toFixed(10).substring(2))
// "0.12104618813524692378"
```

Answer (score 0):

Сложить части после запятой как строки, а в начало поставить 0.